# How to make a pie chart with all the different log codes in Grafana

Tags: logging, grafana, dashboard, grafana-loki, promtail

I have logs with all kind of different codes (there could be more codes added in the future).

I want a pie chart that shows the percentage of the number of times each code appears in the logs.

For example: If I have four times the code "01" and six times the code "02" i want the pie chart to show 40% code "01" and 60% the code "02".

Has anyone done something similar?

I have done it by "hardcoding" the code values but since i have many different codes I cannot do it this way.

Here is my query for now but it doesn't query the right values:
``` sum by(code) (rate({filename=~"$Filename"} | json code="Properties.Code" | __error__=`` [$__interval])) ```

Comment: What is this question about, specifically? You want to know how to write `sum by()` query?

Comment: I want to write this query but without the time range (rate), which doesn't work with this line of code (if I remove the rate) `sum by(code) (rate({filename=~"MYFILENAME"} | json code="Properties.Code" | __error__=`` [$__interval]))`

Comment: You need `count_over_time` instead of `rate`, and most likely `$__range` instead of `$__interval` (if you want to show ratio over time range selected for dashboard).